# Show View Controller based on the users Firebase login state

Tags: swift, firebase, uiviewcontroller, swift3

In my app I want do display different ViewControllers depending on if the user is already logged in or not. Like if the user is logged in present VC_A if not, present VC_B. I tried the following code in my vc_login:

```
 if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc_home") as! ViewController_Home
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

   } else {

     // Do Nothing

   }
```

Comment: your original code with the filled else block was more informative to this question than `// do nothing`

Comment: How are you handling the Firebase token expiration?

Comment: Im doing almost the same and its working for me.         
if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInToTabbarVC", sender: nil)
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that (hints are in the code comments):

```
if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil {
  // user is not logged in
  // present VC_B
} else {
  // user is logged in
  // present VC_A
}
```

Or you can use the ternary conditional operator like this:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil ? presentViewControllerB() : presentViewControllerA()

func presentViewControllerA() {
  // call if logged in
}

func presentViewControllerB() {
  // call if not logged in
}
```